# Husky A200 gmapping transform problem

Tags: navigation, odometry, clearpath, husky, gmapping-demo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Again,

I am trying to use Gmapping on a Clearpath Husky A200 with a Sick LMS100 laser range finder. The problem I am running into is that there is no tf from odom to base_footprint. I tried using a static_transfor_publisher to force a connection, but I have found that I will only get the first map scan and then nothing else as it appears that gmapping updates the map based on changes in the odom->base_footprint transform. Since I was using a static transform it never changes, therefore the map never updates. According to the gmapping package page on the wiki this link is usually provided by the odometry system. Anyone know why it is not being provided in this instance or how I can fix this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59129/husky-a200-gmapping-transform-problem/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as i can see, the `clearpath_husky` stack does not provide any transforms out of the box. However you can get odometry messages from the [husky_bringup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/husky_bringup) package on the /encoder topic. These can be used as input for [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) or [laser_scan_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher), which both can publish the required odom(world) -> base_link transform.

In your case the `laser_scan_matcher` could even be used without any odometry data from the husky plattform at all. You just need to feed your laserscans into it, set `~fixed_frame` to "odom" and both `~use_imu` and `~use_odom` to "false". Even if this odometry is far from optimal, it should give you a starting point for the gmapping usage.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3